# variable undefinded in setParameter method

Tags: forms, symfony, orm

I have the next code in the controller to handle a form, but I'm getting an error that says "Undefined variable: page". Although `$page['community']` is defined before.
This is the code:

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('banish', 'entity', array(
            'label' => $this->trans("Usuarios a expulsar"),
            'class' => 'Pro\MembershipBundle\Entity\Membership',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('SELECT m FROM User u INNER JOIN Membership m ON m.user = u.id WHERE m.community = :community')
                    ->setParameter('community', $page['community']);
                },

        ))
        ->getForm();
```

What can be happening here, and how to solve it?

Comment: Where does `$page` come from?

Comment: @Touki - `$page['community']` is an object containing the `Community` Entity.

Comment: There's nowhere in the code you posted that references `$page`. I assume it's *before* `$form` declaration. Try using `function(EntityRepository $er) use ($page) {`

Comment: @Touki - I've tried, but I'm getting this error; " [Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration | PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got 'SELECT' "

Comment: Well, this is another problem, unrelated to this question.

Comment: @Touki - Thanks for your help. Don't you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: This is too localized and is unlikely going to help anybody else

Comment: @Touki - Whatever you want. The `use` has helped me. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Touki - You may help me out on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332336/unknown-column-in-createformbuilder

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use createQuery instaedof query builder it will solve
or simply

```
$er->createQueryBuilder()
   ->select('m')
   ->from('RedconviveMembershipBundle:User','u')
   ->innerJoin('u.membership','m')
   ->where('m.comunity = :comunity')
   ->setParameter('community', $page['community']);
```

If u can write your associations it will be more easy to find a solution