# Unknown column in createFormBuilder

Tags: forms, symfony

When I try to render a form, I'm getting an error that says "Unknown column u0_.id in on clause" refering to `u.id`. But `id` property and getter is defined for `User` entity. So, what is happening then?

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('banish', 'entity', array(
            'label' => $this->trans("Usuarios a expulsar"),
            'class' => 'Pro\UserBundle\Entity\User',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($page){
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('User')
                          ->select('u')
                          ->from('Pro\UserBundle\Entity\User', 'u')
                          ->innerjoin('Pro\MembershipBundle\Entity\Membership', 'm', 'WITH', 'u.id = m.user')
                          ->where( 'm.community = :community')
                    ->setParameter('community', $page['community']);
                },

        ))
        ->getForm();
```

Comment: Have you updated your database schema? The error sounds like the user's `id` column does not exist. But I am not sure if the way you are joining to the membership entity is valid. Usually you define references and use them for the join. See [doctrine association mapping documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets have a look at the original function `createQueryBuilder()` body which belongs from `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository` ,[*Reference EntityRepository*](https://github.com/tangentlabs/symfony-sandbox/blob/master/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php)

```
/**
 * Create a new QueryBuilder instance that is prepopulated for this entity name
 *
 * @param string $alias
 * @return QueryBuilder $qb
 */
public function createQueryBuilder($alias)
{
    return $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select($alias)
        ->from($this->_entityName, $alias);
}
```

It first parameter is `$alias` and the parameter in `select() , from()` is the same `$alias` and then it calls the `createQueryBuilder()` method of `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager`, now considering your case

```
$er->createQueryBuilder('User')
->select('u')
->from('Pro\UserBundle\Entity\User', 'u')
```

The alias you have selected in `createQueryBuilder()` is `User` which is different from the alias you gave in `select('u') , from('u')` i guess that would be problem ,also when you have defined class in your `entity type field` [you can just directly use it without using again](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html) `from()` method like

```
   $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('banish', 'entity', array(
            'label' => $this->trans("Usuarios a expulsar"),
            'class' => 'Pro\UserBundle\Entity\User',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($page){
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                          ->select('u,m')
                          ->innerjoin('Pro\MembershipBundle\Entity\Membership', 'm', 'WITH', 'u.id = m.user')
                          ->where( 'm.community = :community')
                    ->setParameter('community', $page['community']);
                },

        ))
        ->getForm();
```

Also using `WITH` in join will join the table with multiple conditions like `ON(a.col1=b.col1 AND a.col2=b.col2)` so if you have any property that points to membership defined in your user entity you can just use

```
->innerjoin('u.mapped_property')
```

it will automatically joins your user and membership table like `ON(u.id=m.user_id)`